# How to remove the duplicate values in objects and add the quantity of repeated element?

Tags: javascript

I got to count how many times  the elements are repeating, but I dont know how remove the repeated elements and add the counter just leaving one, example:

```
const list = [

    {name:'A', count: 3 },
    {name:'B', count: 2 },
    {name:'C', count: 1 }

]
```

```js
const list = [

    { id:1, name:'A' },
    { id:2, name:'B' },
    { id:3, name:'A' },
    { id:4, name:'A' },
    { id:5, name:'B' },
    { id:6, name:'C' }

]

let current = null;
let counter  = 0;

 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] != current) {
            current = list[i];
            counter  = 1;
        } else {
            counter += 1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to iterate over the array and then summate the count of the items.
Using some of the ES6 array methods in javascript this is quite easy to do.

```js
const list = [
    { id:1, name:'A' },
    { id:2, name:'B' },
    { id:3, name:'A' },
    { id:4, name:'A' },
    { id:5, name:'B' },
    { id:6, name:'C' }
];

// Create a mapping of name -> count
const mappedListCount = list.reduce((acc, { name, }) => {
  acc[name] = acc[name] ? acc[name] + 1 : 1; // Increment count
  return acc;
}, {});

// Convert the mapping to an array of { name, count }
const listCount = Object.entries(mappedListCount).map(([name, count]) => ({ name, count }));

console.log(listCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you can achieve this using [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create the new array and inside of it with some logic and the use of [finIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) you can fill your array.

this way is more easy than using nested loops or convert the data from one type to another.

```js
const list = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' },
  { id: 3, name: 'A' },
  { id: 4, name: 'A' },
  { id: 5, name: 'B' },
  { id: 6, name: 'C' }
]

const reducer = (accum, currentValue) => {
  const name = currentValue.name;

  // we look for the index of value in the accumulated array.
  const index = accum.findIndex(entry => entry.name === name);

  // if the index is different than -1 it is repeated, otherwise we have to add it.
  if (index !== -1) {
    accum[index].count += 1;
  } else {
    accum.push({
      name: name,
      count: 1
    })
  }

  return accum;
}


const result = list.reduce(reducer, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [

    { id:1, name:'A' },
    { id:2, name:'B' },
    { id:3, name:'A' },
    { id:4, name:'A' },
    { id:5, name:'B' },
    { id:6, name:'C' }

]

//First, get all the names:
const listNames = Array.from(new Set(list.map(item => item.name)))
console.log(listNames)

//Second, for each name, get the count and save to a new list:
const newList = []
listNames.forEach(name => {
    const count = list.filter(item => item.name === name).length
    newList.push({ name, count })
})

console.log(newList)
```